# An image of the projection is dense in the affine space

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I need some help to prove that the projection is a dominant morphism (I raised that question once but still cannot do it). It means that its image is dense Zarisky topolopy. So, there is a hypersurface $X=V(f)=f^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ over some field $\mathbb{k}$, a hyperplane $H=\{x_n=0\}$ and a point $p\in \mathbb{A}^n\setminus H$. The projection $\pi_p$ maps each $x\in X$ to the intersection $(px)\cap H$. Each point of the line $(px)$ looks like $p+t(p-x)$ for some $t\in \mathbb{k}$ hence $p_n+t(p_n-x_n)=0$ and thus $t=\frac{p_n}{x_n-p_n}$. Although it can be easily seen geometrically we have proved that $\pi_p$ is defined on $X\setminus H'$, where $H'=\{x_n=p_n\}$. Thus we are to prove that $\pi_p(X\setminus H')$ is dense in $H$ (to be honest, I believe it should be open).
So, let's try to get the conditions for $y\in H$ to be in $\mathrm{im}(\pi_p)$: $y$ will be in the image of $\pi_p$ iff the line $(py)$ meets $X$ somewhere, that is there exists $t\in\mathbb{k}$ such that $f(p+t(p-y))=0$. Is it obvious that this defines an open set or a set wich contains an open one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does $X$ come into play?

Comment: Thanks a lot, there was a misprint - we are to prove that $\pi_p(X \setminus H')$ is dense but not $\pi_p(x \setminus H')$. I think it was obvious what I meant, or I missed anything?